# Как пользоваться JDDayOfWeek?

Tags: php

Как использовать JDDayOfWeek: имея дату, к примеру, вида 12.02.2012, как узнать по ней день недели?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно так:

```
$cur_date = '12.02.2012';
$arr = explode('.',$cur_date);
echo jddayofweek ( cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, $arr[0],$arr[1], $arr[2]) , 1 );
```

Но думаю, что может быть и более красивый способ.